# How should I handle a Recursive Method Memory dump in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, methods

My issue is that during a Recursive Method call loop, when it passes the IF Statement it dumps (pops) the variable memory. I rewrote an example of what I am seeing below in the simplest way.

**Simple Example of the Problem**

```
class recursion
{
    public function Method_A ($num){
        // Check if the number is greater than 0, if not call Method be to reduce it.
        if ($num>0){
           $this->Method_B($num);
        } else {
            echo "Success".PHP_EOL;
        }

        ## This is where my Problem is
        ## I know I could just add this in the ELSE statement
        ## But I just want to make sure I'm handling Memory Correctly
        echo "Method_A Was Called. Num = " . $num .PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function Method_B ($num){

        $num--;
        $this->Method_A($num);
    }
}

$myNumber = new recursion();
$myNumber->Method_A(10);

// Results
// Success
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 0
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 1
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 2
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 3
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 4
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 5
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 6
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 7
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 8
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 9
// Method_A Was Called. Num = 10
```

I know I could write this to ignore the dump, but I feel like that would be very sloppy and not clean and tidy.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you call "B" in a loop, instead of recursively ?

Comment: A little side not here: As long you are not manipulating a var is s reference, if you manipulate it, it will be copied. So you better use `Method_A (&$num)` and `Method_B ($num)` or make `$num` a class var.

Comment: And you should do  `return $this->Method_B($num);` gives `//results //Success Method_A Was Called. Num = 0`

Comment: @Random This is just an example. In the real situation, Method_B has a specific task to manipulate the data it was given and return it.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think you just solved my dilemma! I'm gonna plug it into my real life situation, but I think you fixed it!

Comment: Didnt now how to make this to an answer, but no need i think, if i still helped a little :)